# Regex: re.finditer not extracting more than one values from a string

Tags: python, python-re

If I only try to find 'host' or 'user_name' the code runs and gives me the right output, however, when I try to find it together (in the same loop), I get no output, although I should be getting the same results I got previously, just in the same line.

```
host = "(?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3}[.][\d]{1,3})(?= - )"
user_name = " (?P<user_name>((?<= - )[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+)|((?<= - )[-]\s))"
time = "(?P<time>(?<=\[).*(?=\]))"
request = "(?P<request>POST.*(?=\"))"

h_u = host+user_name

for item in re.finditer(h_u, logdata):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

I got no output,

Following is what I get when I try to find 'host' and 'user_name' individually:

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178'}
{'host': '156.127.178.177'}
{'host': '100.32.205.59'}
{'host': '168.95.156.240'}
{'host': '71.172.239.195'}
{'host': '180.95.121.94'}
```

Logdata(What I am extracting the values from):

```
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
2.179.103.97 - lind8584 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:36 -0700] "POST /grow/front-end/e-commerce/robust HTTP/2.0" 304 14641
241.114.184.133 - tromp8355 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:37 -0700] "GET /redefine/orchestrate HTTP/1.0" 204 29059
```

Comment: I think you're missing a space between host and user_name, try `h_u = host + " " + user_name`

Comment: Thanks for response however it still doesn't work

Comment: Pattern `h_u` requires that host and username directly follow each other, separated by a single space while it also requires that the host is followed by ` - ` at the same time.

Comment: Even if I remove the requirement for ' - ', the host still runs and so does the user_name, however together they still don't run

Comment: Host and username are separated by " - ", not a single space.

Comment: So instead of space try : `h_u = host + " -" + user_name`